# Disqus Ajax is not taking different thread for diffrent posts in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, disqus

I have one rails application where I am using [Disqus Universal Code](http://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/) for comment function. I am using ajax remote => true function to display my posts content. Here is my disqus code

```
 <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var disqus_shortname = 'ginfy';
      var disqus_identifier = '<%= @posts.id %>';
      (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();
  </script>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

I know that Disqus depends on Site URL and it takes different thread based on different URL but here i am using AJAX [**No CHANGE IN URL**].
check my erb-

```
<%= link_to "Read more","prayers/#{posts_item.id}",:remote => "true" %>
```

When I click on read more then ***Disqus always open with same Thread***. I want Different disqus thread for different posts without sacrificing my Ajax functionality.

I already checked all the question related to this problem but nothing gave me solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the Disqus.reset function when you want to change the thread. Something like the following would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var changeThread = function(){

        DISQUS.reset({
          reload: true,
          config: function () {  
            this.page.identifier = 'new_disqus_identifier';
            this.page.url = 'http://example.com/#!new_content';
            this.page.title = "New Page Title";
            this.language = "fr"; // only if changing the language
          }
        });

    };
</script>

<button onclick=changeThread();>Change the Disqus thread!</button>

<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var disqus_shortname = 'ginfy';
        var disqus_identifier = '<%= @posts.id %>';
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. It works fine. Now i got another problem. I am using `<a href="/#!<%= posts_item.id %>#disqus_thread" data-disqus-identifier="<%= posts_item.id %>"></a>` for showing comments count. When i click on read more and then came back to again my posts list by ajax. Then comment link is not loaded. It is not showing